# Onmouseover() and Onmouseout() not working

Tags: javascript, html

When I hover over the cancel bar, it doesn't execute the onmouseover and onmouseout command. Even worse, it won't execute any of the command itself. How do you fix that ??!!?!?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="background-image: 
url(https://img.michaels.com/L6/3/IOGLO/852866719/201341423/10151236.jpg? fit=inside|1024:1024);">
<button onclick="executeCommand()" style="border: 0; background: 0;"><img 
src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/54/54527.svg" style="padding: 5px 
0px 0px 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px;"></button><div id="search"></div>
<br>  
<script>
function executeCommand(){
document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = "<input type='text' aria- 
label='Search...' placeholder='Search...' value='' id='fx' style='padding: 10px 
50px 10px 5px; background-color: #33333366; border: 0'></input><button 
onclick='deletes()' style='padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px; border: 
0;'>Cancel</button><button onclick='entre()' style='padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px; 
border: 0; background-color: #77bbffff;'>Enter</button><button 
onclick='unsrch()' style='padding: 0px 4px 2px 4px; border-color: #ff0000ff; 
background-color: #e3e3e3ff; color: #ff0000ff; text-decoration: bold;' 
id='hoverover'><b>x</b></button>";
}
function deletes(){
document.getElementById("fx").value="";
}
function entre(){

}
function unsrch(){
document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = "";
}
document.getElementById("hoverover").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
function mouseOver(){
document.getElementById("hoverover").style.background-color = "#555555ff";
}
document.getElementById("hoverover").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
function mouseOut(){
document.getElementById("hoverover").style.background-color = "#e3e3e3ff";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try attaching your handlers in Javascript instead, rather than being inlined in the HTML (which is bad practice and hard to manage).

Comment: Check your console for error messages, they should make things clear. I've downvoted because you obviously made no attempt at debugging it yourself.

Comment: I did make an attempt. I once tried it in <style>, but that didn't work so instead I tried in JavaScript. when that didn't work either, I just gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, you have to type css attributes in camelcase:

```
document.getElementById("hoverover").style.backgroundColor = "#e3e3e3ff";
```

Another problem of your code is:

You generate an element inside your `execudeCommand()` function but you initialize the mouseevents for `document.getElementById("hoverover")` right before this element exists. You have to create a delegate to your mouseover/mouseout listeners **after** adding the element to the dom like this:

```
function executeCommand() {
    document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = "<input type='text' aria- label='Search...' placeholder='Search...' value='' id='fx' style='padding: 10px 50px 10px 5px; background-color: #33333366; border: 0'/>";
    document.getElementById("search").innerHTML += "<button onclick='deletes()' style='padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px; border: 0;'>Cancel</button>";
    document.getElementById("search").innerHTML += "<button onclick='entre()' style='padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px; border: 0; background-color: #77bbffff;'>Enter</button>";
    document.getElementById("search").innerHTML += "<button onclick='unsrch()' style='padding: 0px 4px 2px 4px; border-color: #ff0000ff; background-color: #e3e3e3ff; color: #ff0000ff; text-decoration: bold;' class='hoverover-class'><b>x</b></button>";

    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.hoverover-class');

    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].onmouseover = mouseOver;
        buttons[i].onmouseout = mouseOut;
    }
}

function mouseOver(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#555555ff";
}

function mouseOut(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#e3e3e3ff";
}
executeCommand();
```

Last thing: Try to avoid using the `id=""` attribute if you create multiple elements. You can use `document.querySelector()` instead as seen in the example above:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Comment: Thanks. Now I can click the search icon, but still can't execute the onmouseover command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code but with edits to allow for the functionality that you want!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body style="background-image: url(https://img.michaels.com/L6/3/IOGLO/852866719/201341423/10151236.jpg?%20fit=inside|1024:1024);">
    <button onclick="executeCommand()" style="border: 0; background: 0;">
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/54/54527.svg" style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
    </button>
    <div id="search"></div>
    <br>
    <script>
        function executeCommand() {

           document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = "<input type='text' \
           aria-label = 'Search...' placeholder = 'Search...' value = '' id = 'fx' style = 'padding: 10px 50px 10px \
           5px; background - color: #33333366; border: 0'></input>\
           <button onclick = 'deletes()' style = 'padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px; border: \
            0; '>Cancel</button><button onclick='entre()' style='padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;\
            border: 0; background - color: #77bbffff; '>Enter</button><button \
            onclick = 'unsrch()' style = 'padding: 0px 4px 2px 4px; border-color: #ff0000ff; \
            background - color: #e3e3e3ff; color: #ff0000ff; text - decoration: bold; ' \
            id = 'hoverover'  onmouseover='mouseOver();' onmouseout='mouseOut();')> <b>x</b></button > ";
        }

        function deletes() {
            document.getElementById("fx").value = "";
        }

        function entre() {

        }

        function unsrch() {
            document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = "";
        }

        function mouseOver() {
            document.getElementById("hoverover").style.backgroundColor = "#555555ff";
        }

        function mouseOut() {
            document.getElementById("hoverover").style.backgroundColor = "#e3e3e3ff";
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

These are the changes made:

1. I added line breaks to the `innerHTML` to make it more readable
2. I added `onmouseover='mouseOver();' onmouseout='mouseOut();` which call your script
   3.I removed the two lines `document.getElementById("hoverover").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};` and 
   `document.getElementById("hoverover").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};`, since they were added to the `button` when writing the inner html

Hope that solved all your issues!